# Grid Layout implementing Specific Buttons ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, grid-layout

I'm having trouble; I'm trying to implement a cinema booking system however I cannot set an actionListener to a specific button on different grids. The way I want it to work is each user will have a session in which he can pick seats and a ticket price such as student rate, old age pensionate rates. Anyway, I cannot seem to be able to add actionListener, so when he picks seats, those become unavailable while the program is running. Thank you.

```
// Load Libraries
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class cinemaSystem {
    // Global Variables
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // Creates JFrame
    JLabel title;
    JButton l[][], m[][], r[][]; // Names grid of JButtons
    JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3;

    // Constructor
    public cinemaSystem(){

            title = new JLabel("Cinema Booking");
            title.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 30));
            title.setLocation(12,5);
            title.setSize(600, 60);

            frame.setLayout(null); // Setting Grid Layout
            // panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(seat,row));
            l = new JButton[4][4]; // Allocating Size of Grid
            panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4));
            panel1.setBackground(Color.black);
            panel1.setBounds(20, 70, 200, 140);
            for(int y = 0; y <4 ; y++){
                    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
                        l[x][y] = new JButton("L" + y + x); // Creates New JButton
                        // l[x][y].addActionListener(this);
                        panel1.add(l[x][y]); //adds button to grid
                    }
            }

            m = new JButton[4][2]; // Allocating Size of Grid
            panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,4));
            panel2.setBackground(Color.black);
            panel2.setBounds(240, 140, 200, 70);
            for(int y = 0; y <2 ; y++){
                    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
                        m[x][y] = new JButton("M" + y + x); // Creates New JButton
                        panel2.add(m[x][y]); //adds button to grid
                    }
            }

            r = new JButton[4][4]; // Allocating Size of Grid
            panel3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4));
            panel3.setBackground(Color.black);
            panel3.setBounds(460, 70, 200, 140);
            for(int y = 0; y <4 ; y++){
                    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
                        r[x][y] = new JButton("R" + y + x); // Creates New JButton
                        panel3.add(r[x][y]); //adds button to grid
                    }
            }

            frame.add(title);
            frame.add(panel1);
            frame.add(panel2);
            frame.add(panel3);
            frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(680, 280));
            frame.setTitle("Cinema Booking");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
            frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
    }

    // Main Class
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new cinemaSystem(); //makes new ButtonGrid with 2 parameters
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the text held by the pressed JButton simply by calling `getActionCommand()` on the ActionEvent object passed into the `actionPerformed(...)` method, or you can get which button was pressed via its `getSource()` method. Either of these can help you find the JButton in  your arrays and inactivate it.

Other suggestions:

- Don't use `this` as your ActionListener. Instead consider using an anonymous inner class or private inner class. This will make your code much more flexible and your ActionListeners much simpler.
- Try to follow Java naming conventions including being sure that class names start with capital letters and that variables and method names begin with lower-case letters. This will make it much easier for others (such as *us*!) to be able to understand your code at a glance.
- Avoid use of absolute layouts as it makes your GUI's hard to maintain and doesn't allow your GUI's to re-size flexibly for different OS's or screen resolutions. For instance your current GUI looks like this on my screen:

[image]

For example this ActionListener will show which button was pressed and will inactivate that button:

```
private class MyListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     System.out.println("Button pressed: " + e.getActionCommand());
     ((JButton)e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
  }
}
```

Which can be added to the JButtons in a fashion similar to this...

```
  ActionListener listener = new MyListener();

  for (int i = 0; i < leftBtns.length; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < leftBtns[i].length; j++) {
        JButton btn = new JButton("L" + i + j);
        btn.setFont(btn.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, BTN_FONT_SIZE));
        btn.addActionListener(listener);
        leftPanel.add(btn);
     }
  }
```

Plus using appropriate layout managers produced a GUI that looked like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have now decided to go with JToggleButtons and I have had success. How Toggling the buttons and printing its label. E.g.: If I click on L00, it prints out L00 true, then selects it; if I click again it unselects it and prints L00 false. Which is great. Thank you.